# Formatting strings in a character vector of a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have a data frame (let's call it DF) that looks like this:

```
 options(stringsAsFactors = F)
 letters <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
 value <- c(.44, .54, .21, .102, .002)
 test <- c("2", "c(1,4)", "1", "3:4", "c(1,2)")

 DF <- data.frame(cbind(letters, value, test))
 DF$value <- as.numeric(DF$value)
```

This is what DF looks like if you were to print it:

```
#DF
#      letters   value    test
#1       A       0.440     2
#2       B       0.540    c(1,4)
#3       C       0.210     1
#4       D       0.102    3:4
#5       E       0.002    c(1,2)
```

My main issue is DF$test.  For any cell that has more than one value (ie: 3:4, c(1,2)), I would like the the cell to have the formating of X:Y , given that X and Y are numeric values.

Can someone help?  Please note that `DF$test` is a character vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another `gsub` option that uses 2 `gsub`s:

```
DF$test2 <- gsub(",",":", gsub(".*c\\((.*)\\).*", "\\1", DF$test))
DF
#  letters value   test test2
#1       A 0.440      2     2
#2       B 0.540 c(1,4)   1:4
#3       C 0.210      1     1
#4       D 0.102    3:4   3:4
#5       E 0.002 c(1,2)   1:2
```

The first `gsub` extracts everything between the `c(` and `)` and the second `gsub` replaces any `,` with `:`. This would work if you had > 2 numbers in your `c()`. I.e. `c(1,2,3)` would become `1:2:3`.

Answer (score 1):

With:

```
tst <- gsub('[c()]','',DF$test)
tst <- strsplit(tst, '[,:]')
DF$test <- sapply(tst, paste0, collapse = ':')
```

or in one go:

```
DF$test <- sapply(strsplit(gsub('[c()]','',DF$test), '[,:]'), paste0, collapse = ':')
```

your data.frame now looks like:

> ```
> > DF
>   letters value test
> 1       A 0.440    2
> 2       B 0.540  1:4
> 3       C 0.210    1
> 4       D 0.102  3:4
> 5       E 0.002  1:2
> ```

The advantage of this is that it also works with strings in `DF$test` that are longer than 2 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

`gsub` should get you there

```
DF$test <- gsub(".+(\\d+).(\\d+).+", "\\1:\\2", DF$test)
```

Comment: Thanks! but what if i wanted to do that globally?  so i'm not hard coding 1 and 2?

Comment: 1 and 2 are not hard-coded. `\\1` is a regex placeholder for the match between the first pair of parentheses and `\\2` for the second pair. I have made one edit to account for a scenario with multi-digit numers, e,g, 12, 123, etc.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
DF$test <- sapply(str_extract_all(DF$test, '[0-9]+'), paste, collapse=":")
DF$test
#[1] "2"   "1:4" "1"   "3:4" "1:2"
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
DF$test <- sapply(regmatches(DF$test, gregexpr('[0-9]+', DF$test)), paste, collapse=":")
```